# Search a number in string using a charCodes and one for loop that starts from the end

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fromcharcode

I have string:
const text = "I spent 1430 USD today"

I need to get the amount 1430 using the for loop from the end
Forbidden: do not use parseInt, parseFloat, Number, +str, 1 * str, 1 / str, 0 + str, etcc

Limitations: 1 for loop, charCodeAt

I tried solving it and it makes sense that the numbers would be written in reverse order. How can I avoid this without using reverse (or other native methods) or additional loops \ functions ?

```
function searchAmount(str) {
  let amount = 0;

  for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);

    if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) {
      amount = amount * 10 + (charCode - 48);
    }
  }
  return amount;
}

console.log(searchAmount(text));
```

Comment: The limitations are harsh. Here is a simple version: `const nums = str.split(' ').filter(word => /^\d+$/.test(word)).map(Number);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply the found digit with 10^0, 10^1, 10^2 etc., according to its "position", not the already calculated amount up to that point.

You could do that by keeping a multiplication factor, starting with `1`, and multiplied by `10` every time after you added a digit:

```js
function searchAmount(str) {
  let amount = 0,
    factor = 1;

  for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);

    if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) {
      amount += (charCode - 48) * factor;
      factor *= 10;
    }
  }
  return amount;
}

console.log(searchAmount("I spent 1430 USD today"));
```

Comment: You likely want to bug out when you find something not a number or you will get problems with `I spent 1430 USD today at 10 o'clock`

Comment: @mplungjan that is true, but since the question did not come with any mention whether such a case is valid, or what exactly should be returned if it was, I think that can probably be ignored for now.

Comment: @mplungjan within the scope of the task, there is no need to do so. I'm learning how to use charCodes. Thanks for the reply!